# need help in get values from array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi need help getting values from array
first i have get consecutive values from below array eg=>id:1,2 ignore if consecutive values doesn`t not exits
            after getting values find the differences between the bids of consecutive values , then sum up all the values of bids(consecutive values) ??

```
        $bidperpage = array([0]=>array(['id']=>1,['bid']='10',['page']='5'),
        [1]=>array(['id']=>2,['bid']='15',['page']='5'),
        [2]=>array(['id']=>9,['bid']='20',['page']='2'),
        [3]=>array(['id']=>3,['bid']='30',['page']='7'),
        [4]=>array(['id']=>4,['bid']='40',['page']='7'),
        [5]=>array(['id']=>5,['bid']='50',['page']='9'),
        [6]=>array(['id']=>6,['bid']='60',['page']='4'),
        [7]=>array(['id']=>8,['bid']='70',['page']='4'));



function checkconsecutivevalue($array) {
 $ret  = array();
 $temp = array();
 foreach($array as $val) {
  if(next($array) == ($val + 1))
     $temp[] = $val;
  else
     if(count($temp) > 0) {
        $temp[] = $val;
        $ret[]  = $temp[0].':'.end($temp);
        $temp   = array();
     }
     else
        $ret[] = $val;
   }         


 return $ret;
 }
```

Comment: What hage you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, your array definition is a flat-out syntax error. It should be

```
$bidperpage = array(
    0 => array('id' => 1, 'bid' => '10', 'page' => '5'),
    etc...
);
```

Note the proper use of the `=>` operator, and the LACK of `[]` braces.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, to my mind is using `usort`:

```
$bidperpage = array(array('id'=>1,'bid'=>'10','page'=>'5'),
        array('id'=>2,'bid'=>'15','page'=>'5'),
        array('id'=>9,'bid'=>'20','page'=>'2'),
        array('id'=>3,'bid'=>'30','page'=>'7'),
        array('id'=>4,'bid'=>'40','page'=>'7'),
        array('id'=>5,'bid'=>'50','page'=>'9'),
        array('id'=>11,'bid'=>'60','page'=>'q'),
        array('id'=>8,'bid'=>'70','page'=>'4'));

//Sort function
function sortById($a,$b)
{
    if ($a['id'] === $b['id'])
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['id'] > $b['id'] ? 1 : -1);
}
usort($bidperpage,'sortById');
```

More info: [See the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
Do remember, I assumed the key `id` will always be pressent, if this is not the case, you might want to add an extra check to the callback function:

```
function sortById($a,$b)
{
    if (!isset($a['id']) && !isset($b['id']))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (!isset($a['id']))
    {
        return 1;//move to end of array
    }
    if (!isset($b['id']))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if ($a['id'] === $b['id'])
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['id'] > $b['id'] ? 1 : -1);
}
```

This function needn't be that verbose, but since I get the impression you haven't tried that much, I'll leave that up to you.